# Android GUI - How to force a button to the next line?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

Sorry if I'm asking such a basic question. I have tried to google all morning, and read through the documentations at developer.android.com, but I couldn't find a solution.

In short, I would like to make an interface that looks like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to bring the 2 buttons to the next line, but I still have no luck with that. If I change the android:orientation="horizontal" to "vertical", everything was aligned vertically. I tried to bring the line android:orientation="vertical" inside the Button tag, but that didn't seem to work.

What else can I try? Would somebody give me a few pointers? (I'm new at Android development and all these XML stuff).

---

Below is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<EditText android:id="@+id/txt_Input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="@string/txt_Input"

        android:layout_weight="4"                      
/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_Send" 

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:onClick="sendMessage"
/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_Send" 

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:onClick="sendMessage"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use RelativeLayout, and your buttons should look something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_Send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_Input"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_Send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_Input"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/send"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have all of the items in a LinearLayout with it's orientation set to Horizontal so it lines up all of the UI components horizontally.  What you need to do it use a RelativeLayout and set the buttons to layout below the EditText.

Comment: Alternatively, set orientation to vertical and use a nested horizontal linear layout to enclose the buttons below the edittext.

Comment: @withoutclass: that would be less efficient than just relative layout

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a difference.

Comment: Thank you, Casey. Now I know there's another type of layout.

Comment: @Asahi Yes it would be slightly less efficient as well as resulting in uglier layout code, but it works as a solution.  It's why I didn't post it as an answer.